# Патч private на public

Tags: c#

Как пропатчить переменную в dll с private на public удаленно?

Так не работает - пробовал

```
TypeDefinition Useable = rustAssembly.MainModule.GetType("Useable");
Useable.GetMethod("Refresh").SetPublic(true);
```

Comment: Декомпилировать сборку, изменить, снова скомпилировать.

Comment: Не имею исходного кода - библиотека игровая Assembly-CSharp.dll

Comment: _Декомпилировать_ - вот и появится исходный код.

Comment: если разобрать - уже невозможно собрать в dll - так как dll под обфускатором

Comment: Если переменная объявлена как `private`, значит библиотечный код безаговорочно ей доверяет, не проверяя постоянно на безошибочность и согласованность. **Если вы начнёте менять закрытые переменные, то с очень большой вероятностью рассинхронизируете состояние различных частей объекта или даже группы объектов.** Это приведёт к непредсказуемой работе программы в целом.

Comment: 1) Поискать описание .NET DLL, и особенно метаданных. Либо 2) сделать две копии DLL из одного и того же кода, только в одном переменную объявить публичной, а в другом приватной. Сравнить. Выказать гипотезу, что между private и public разница в 1-2 бита, и понять, где они должны быть. Разобравшись, пропатчить в нужном месте DLL. Но если она подписана, то oops, подпись окажется неверной.

Comment: Зачем патчить, если есть рефлексия

Comment: А зачем вам? Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Есть Assembly-CSharp - хочу сделать переадресацию в мою dll - но переменные в Assembly-CSharp под private и нужен к ним доступ из моей dll